# No module named 'tools' while importing scikits.talkbox

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, signal-processing

I just installed scikits.talkbox, and tried using it in my program. But I get the following error

> 'ImportError: No module named 'tools'

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: did you install through - `pip install scikits.talkbox`?

Comment: Yep. That's how I installed it

Comment: are you using windows? are you sure that installation was successful? this package requires MS visual studio c++ 10.0.

Comment: Oh sorry. Forgot to mention. I'm using a Mac. I have numpy, scipy and setuptools on my system, and I have python 3.5. Those were the requirements mentioned on the Github page

https://github.com/cournape/talkbox/blob/master/INSTALL.txt

Comment: i tried both in windows and linux but its working for me, sorry for not helping you :(

Comment: Oh no problem. Thank you for trying :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Something wrong with scikits.talkbox with Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365733/something-wrong-with-scikits-talkbox-with-python3)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem，just run `pip install tools`

Comment: That just changes the error for me to `AttributeError: module 'tools' has no attribute '__all__'`.