# Something wrong with scikits.talkbox with Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-2.x, scikits

I am migrating a Python program from 2.10 to 3.6. The packages `scikits.talkbox` is part of it. However, I cannot figure out how to use it any more. The installation from `pip` seems to work fine but I cannot import it. Has anyone faced this problem before ?

```
[manjaro@manjaro-pc ~]$ python --version
Python 3.6.0

[manjaro@manjaro-pc ~]$ sudo pip install scikits.talkbox
Collecting scikits.talkbox
  Using cached scikits.talkbox-0.2.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikits.talkbox)
Installing collected packages: scikits.talkbox
  Running setup.py install for scikits.talkbox ... done
Successfully installed scikits.talkbox-0.2.5

[manjaro@manjaro-pc ~]$ python 
Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan 16 2017, 12:12:55) 
[GCC 6.3.1 20170109] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import scikits.talkbox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scikits/talkbox/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    __all__ += tools.__all__
AttributeError: module 'tools' has no attribute '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is this link [Error while importing scikits.talkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438250/error-while-importing-scikits-talkbox)
Even I am facing this issue
I have switched to librosa

There is another way for MFCC features: python_speech_features
http://python-speech-features.readthedocs.io/en/latest/