# Python scikits.talkbox can't be used from pip -- want to use lpc

Tags: python, macos, pip, scikits

I was trying to use `scikits.talkbox.lpc` on Mac OS X. Here are what I tried:

```
#Python 2      
sudo pip install scikits.talkbox. (Edit: no dot after talkbox here)
python
>>> from scikits.talkbox import lpc
```

> ImportError: No module named scikits.talkbox

```
#Python 3
sudo pip3 install scikits.talkbox  
python3    
>>> from scikits.talkbox import lpc
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scikits/talkbox/**init**.py", line 3, in 
>       from tools import *
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools'

Any idea how to make use of `scikits.talkbox`? Or if it is not usable any longer, is there some recommended way to extract LPC features from audio?

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365733/something-wrong-with-scikits-talkbox-with-python3) suggests using librosa -- but they do not have an lpc module.

Comment: You should be using `virtualenv` for python development so you do not mess around with sudo and make your python development a bit hazy. In terms of what you have done. I ran `pip install scikits.talkbox` and ran pythn and imported the lib and it worked. I hope you do not run it with `pip install scikits.talkbox.` i.e dot at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The dot was autogenerated when double clicking space. It was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `lpc` in `scikits.talkbox` sources. But there is a submodule `linpred.levinson_lpc`; I think you want

```
from scikits.talkbox.linpred.levinson_lpc import lpc
```

Comment: I definitely was able to execute the above import of `lpc` for python 2.7 within a virtualenv. I think his distro may have many different installs and without a `pip uninstall` we could have conflict of versions.

Comment: Now within `virtualenv`, both `from scikits.talkbox.linpred import lpc` and `from scikits.talkbox.linpred.levinson_lpc import lpc` work. Thanks guys!