# Cannot pip install scikits.talkbox on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, python-3.7, scikits

I'm trying to pip install scikits.talkbox on my MacOS. I use Python 3.7.3

If I run

```
pip install scikits.talkbox
```

or

```
pip3 install scikits.talkbox
```

I get the following errors (I hope I did include everything)

```
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3287:21: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
    *type = tstate->exc_type;
            ~~~~~~  ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3288:22: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
    *value = tstate->exc_value;
                     ^~~~~~~~~
                     curexc_value
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
    PyObject *curexc_value;
              ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3289:19: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
    *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  curexc_traceback
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
    PyObject *curexc_traceback;
              ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3298:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
    tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
               ~~~~~~  ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3299:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
    tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                        ^~~~~~~~~
                        curexc_value
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
    PyObject *curexc_value;
              ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3300:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
    tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     curexc_traceback
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
    PyObject *curexc_traceback;
              ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3301:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
    tstate->exc_type = type;
    ~~~~~~  ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3302:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
    tstate->exc_value = value;
            ^~~~~~~~~
            curexc_value
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
    PyObject *curexc_value;
              ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3303:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
    tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
            curexc_traceback
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
    PyObject *curexc_traceback;
              ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3319:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
    tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
               ~~~~~~  ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3320:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
    tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                        ^~~~~~~~~
                        curexc_value
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
    PyObject *curexc_value;
              ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3321:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
    tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     curexc_traceback
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
    PyObject *curexc_traceback;
              ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3322:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
    tstate->exc_type = *type;
    ~~~~~~  ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3323:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
    tstate->exc_value = *value;
            ^~~~~~~~~
            curexc_value
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
    PyObject *curexc_value;
              ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3324:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
    tstate->exc_traceback = *tb;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
            curexc_traceback
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
    PyObject *curexc_traceback;
              ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3537:25: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyNumber_Int' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        PyObject* tmp = PyNumber_Int(x); if (!tmp) return (PY_LONG_LONG)-1;
                        ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3537:19: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') with an expression of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
        PyObject* tmp = PyNumber_Int(x); if (!tmp) return (PY_LONG_LONG)-1;
                  ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3558:25: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyNumber_Int' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        PyObject* tmp = PyNumber_Int(x); if (!tmp) return (PY_LONG_LONG)-1;
                        ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3558:19: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') with an expression of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
        PyObject* tmp = PyNumber_Int(x); if (!tmp) return (PY_LONG_LONG)-1;
                  ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My suspect is that there is some problems with setuptools, which I have just upgraded, no results. Any ideas?

Comment: That's the part of the output where it shows the command used to install. You need to post the _actual error_ part of the output, and the `pip` command you used. Also are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I have included the required information. If there is anything still missing, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same errors on Python 3.7.4 on macOS. It's related to the package's Cython-related codes:

```
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3287:21: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
    *type = tstate->exc_type;
            ~~~~~~  ^
scikits/talkbox/tools/src/cffilter.c:3288:22: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
    *value = tstate->exc_value;
                     ^~~~~~~~~
                     curexc_value
```

First of, the [scikits.talkbox](https://pypi.org/project/scikits.talkbox/) package is *very old* with its last release *waaaaay back* in Aug 28, 2009 (see [0.25](https://pypi.org/project/scikits.talkbox/#history)), which is about 10 years ago! It seems it is not compatible with or was not even ported yet for Python 3.

It does install successfully on Python 2.7, though:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.16
$ python -m pip install numpy scipy
...
$ python -m pip install scikits.talkbox
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting scikits.talkbox
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/a0/410eb932e1765186a4728d1c9b28410695d554c47439bcb69a407d5d3921/scikits.talkbox-0.2.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/cerberus/.virtualenvs/test-py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scikits.talkbox) (1.16.5)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikits.talkbox
  Building wheel for scikits.talkbox (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for scikits.talkbox: filename=scikits.talkbox-0.2.5-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl size=68422 sha256=4585d129fe5ba2de97935f723f2d84a8b908480528c66cf00714f8a5f56c6bee
  Stored in directory: /Users/cerberus/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/40/06/3f/05c8ab2b4a0cfb32ad02c449e5c949c592cd0c6458db0e7f5f
Successfully built scikits.talkbox
Installing collected packages: scikits.talkbox
Successfully installed scikits.talkbox-0.2.5
```

If you want Python 3 support, you'll have to raise an issue over at the [scikits.talkbox Github page](https://github.com/cournape/talkbox), but judging from the history on that repo, it seems the author is not active anymore on that project.

Out of curiousity, I tried finding a workaround for installing on Python 3. Basically, the package includes pre-compiled Cython files, which are not compatible with Python 3 (giving the errors with `*.c` files). I tried to re-compile it with Cython on Python3.7:

```
# download the source code from PyPi
$ wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/a0/410eb932e1765186a4728d1c9b28410695d554c47439bcb69a407d5d3921/scikits.talkbox-0.2.5.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf scikits.talkbox-0.2.5.tar.gz
$ cd scikits.talkbox-0.2.5/

# re-compile with Cython on Python 3.7
$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.4
$ python3 -m pip install numpy scipy cython
$ find . -name '*.pyx' -exec cython {} \;
$ python3 -m pip install .
...
Successfully installed scikits.talkbox-0.2.5
```

It seems I got it successfully installed **BUT** when you use it:

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.4 (default, Sep  7 2019, 18:29:04) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scikits.talkbox
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/cerberus/.virtualenvs/test-py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scikits/talkbox/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    __all__ += tools.__all__
AttributeError: module 'tools' has no attribute '__all__'
>>>
```

..which is the same unresolved, unnoticed error reported in the package's repo:
https://github.com/cournape/talkbox/issues/8

---

So... it seems your only options are to:

- Use Python 2.7
- Use a different, more Python3-compatible library

  - Ex. [librosa](https://github.com/librosa/librosa) as suggested in [Something wrong with scikits.talkbox with Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44365733/2745495)

Comment: Many thanks for your effort. Yes, works with python 2.7, but I will not use it, it will be deprecated soon and I need a reliable code on the long term. I will have to find an alternative, I was trying to use the LPC module inside, which is not included in librosa.